# Which title would be the most acceptable in doing a literature review for an academic research?

Tags: academic-writing

I am doing a literature review on Driver Drowsiness/Distraction Detection topic and I want to choose my title. Which one of these would sound the most professional:

- An investigation on various Driver Drowsiness Detection or Driver Distraction Detection methods in the automobile industry.
- An investigation on various techniques for Driver Distraction and Drowsiness Detection in the automobile industry.
- An investigation on Driver Drowsiness and Driver Distraction Detection techniques used in the automobile industry.

Is it worth repeating the word driver, and is it better to use "and" instead of "or" to differentiate between the two terms ?

Comment: for moderators: if you think this question is not related to this community, please migrate it to Academia community.

Comment: [is it better **to use y instead **of it**]

Comment: @Lambie  What do you mean ? I have just edited the last sentence.

Answer (score 1):

I would make it like this:

> Driver Drowsiness and Distraction Detection Techniques In the Automobile
>   Industry

- No need to use the word "investigation," but you may want to include it if it's a specific type of investigation: observational study, controlled trial, etc.
- Techniques/Methods - you use what sounds better to you. I would use "technique," because this sounds like what a driver does spontaneously; a "method" sounds like something learned.
- No need to repeat the words.
- You capitalize all the words, except "and" and "the."

Comment: Thanks for the bullet points. I will use " An Investigation" in the beginning because our assignment should be investigating/studying one topic from writer's perspective.